# Subbase and projection function problem

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

[image]I have no problems with subbases in topology but I have problems dealing with
projection functions and possibly subbases together.

A subset A of **R**$\times$**R** is bounded if there exists an integer n such that A$\subset$ $S_n$($(0,0)$ ) Show that for a any bounded subset A of **R** $\times$**R**,
$\pi_1$(A) $\times$ $\pi_2$(A) is a rectangle no matter the shape of A.

**My attempt**

Assume A$\subset$ $S_n$($(0,0)$) .This
means A is centred at $(0,0)$ within
the bounded ball of size n.Since A $\subset$ **R**$\times$**R** , we get
A $\subset$  **R**$\times$**R** $\subset$
$S_n$($(0,0)$) which means $\pi_1$(A) $\times$ $\pi_2$(A) is a rectangle no matter the shape of A.

Any help would be appreciated in dealing with this topic.

Source:*A First Course In Topology*,Robert Conover

Comment: What if $A=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ which is surely bounded? Then $\pi_1(A)=\{0,1\}= \pi_2(A)$ and their product is the set of  4 points $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ which I would *not* call a rectangle. So how does Conover **define** a rectangle in the first place?

Comment: He gives a theorem The collection of subsets of the plane S={(a,b)$\times$ R,R $\times$(c,d):a<b,c<d,a,b,c,d$\in$R }of all strips in the plane is a subbasis for the usual topology on the plane

Comment: well, that’s true but says nothing about rectangles.

Comment: “A rectangle in the plane ,though,is the intersection of two strips”,pg 81

Comment: Then, my example fro above is **not** the intersection of two strips….

Comment: So I guess in my proof I should create such a strip and go from there ?

Comment: No, you cannot prove it because it’s false.

Comment: Jeez, that is bad. What was Conover thinking?. Can it be fixed to be proved?

Comment: No, you can say it’s contained in a rectangle. But it’s not an important thing anyway.

Comment: Ok, but I want to solve everything.

Comment: He does mention A$\ne$ $\pi_1$(A) $\times$ $\pi_2$(A), indeed $\pi_1$(A) $\times$ $\pi_2$(A) is necessarily a rectangle in the plane X $\times$ Y

Comment: Only if those factor sets are intervals.